Flutter Slidable - How to set height of slidable
I am developing Flutter app and I added Slidable, which is working well for me.
Only problem I have is with its height. I am unable to set height of Slidable to be same as my card, sending image below. I need that red part to be same height as my white card. I tried to increase size of my Card, but it increase size for Slidable as well.
Here is my code:
return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 6.0),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Flexible(
                    child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: notes.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          final note = notes[index];
                          return Slidable(
                            endActionPane: ActionPane(
                              extentRatio: 0.35,
                              motion: const ScrollMotion(),
                              children: [
                                SlidableAction(
                                  onPressed: (BuildContext context) {
                                    showDialog(
                                      context: context,
                                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                        return DeleteConfirmationDialog(
                                            noteId: note.id);
                                      },
                                    ).then((result) {
                                      if (result == 'OK') {
                                        _deleteNote(note.id);
                                      }
                                    });
                                  },
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                                  foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                                  icon: Icons.delete_outline,
                                  label: 'Vymazať',
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            child: HomeCard(
                              note: note,
                              onTap: () => _navigateAndUpdateNote(note),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );



Are you sure its not caused by the padding widget you have there?
Padding( padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 6.0),

Yes, I am sure. When I remove that padding, it only move ma card to the edge of screen. But problem is with height of that red Slidable

Slidable(
  endActionPane: ActionPane(
    extentRatio: 0.2,// add as per your need.
    motion: const ScrollMotion(),
    children: [
      SlidableAction(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
        icon: Icons.delete_outline,
        label: 'Delete',
      ),
    ],
  ),
  child: HomeCard(
    note: note,
    onTap: () => _navigateAndUpdateNote(note),
  ),
);


This is changing how much space of screen slidable takes. It does not affect height in any way.

I found this solution,
set the spacing in the builder.
return ListView.separated(
  itemCount: data.length,
  separatorBuilder: (context, index) => SizedBox(height: 8),
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => CardTodoListWidget(getIndex: index),
);

and set the widget's spacing to 0.
child: Card(
  color: Colors.white,
  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0), //set 0
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
  ),
  child: Material(
    color: Colors.transparent,
    child: InkWell(
  ...

